# Angular 13 compilation issue (Error: Importing unexpected symbol ɵɵinvalidFactory while compiling @angular/core)

Tags: angular, npm, ivy, angular13

I have an Angular 13 app which was working fine until now. In one of my feature branches, I added some components and packages from another project(lesser angular version), and this compilation error started showing up:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Importing unexpected symbol
> ɵɵinvalidFactory while compiling @angular/core
> at validateAndRewriteCoreSymbol

After some google searches, my guess is this has to do with Ivy compatibility with some packages, but I'm kind of stuck and couldn't think of a solution and wasted lot of time. Any idea/solutions for this that anyone knows about?

[image: build error]

This is my package.json content

```
{
  "name": "userportal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.8",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "angular-tawk": "^0.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^13.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: `I added some components and packages from another project` how exactly? Did you copy content of `node_modules`?

Comment: I have had this issue before forgot how i fixed it. But i do think it might be some package.json version missmatch. could you post your packages you have installed

Comment: @JSONDerulo No, copied packages from package.json and ran npm install

Comment: Which packages have you added? Maybe one of the packages has an old Angular version set as peer dependency. (like `^11.0.0`, and not `>= 11.0.0`)

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen Added! what do you think?

Comment: I think it you builder package is a couple of versions ahead of the app. try to change it to `@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.2` or `@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.0`  i think minor versions should be fine though